# Simple way to duplicate server nodes with replicated caches

Tags: ignite

I'm using 2.7.6 with one server and dozens of clients.

I want to add the second server that will duplicate the data on the first one and will backup periodically the persistent data.

So I start the second one which starts synchronizing with the first one.

The problem is that this process takes too much time.

So I tried to simply copy the work folder of the first server into the folder of the second one.

This led me to the following message:

```
  Failed to add node to topology because it has the same hash code for partitioned affinity as one of existing nodes
```

Ok, I understand why this happens. But how to speed up the sync process? Maybe there is some other method to make the full duplicate of persistence to use it in another server's node?

**Added**

It seems it is not possible to just create a new server node and move the needed data inside its work folder. It can be done for simple nodes with a small amount of data, but for the big ones, the problem occurs with /db//metastorage folder.

If don't touch it and keep it from the new server node, the message

```
 No server nodes found for cache client
```

emerges on the server's start. On the other side if to replace it with the folder from the duplicating server this exception

```
Apache.Ignite.Core.Common.IgniteException: 'Failed to get page IO instance (page content is corrupted)'
```

occurs.

Comment: What do you mean by "too long"? How much data are we talking here?

Comment: About 30 minutes for the first run. The amount of data is about 10Gb

Answer (score 1):

I think it should work by copying db files.

You may try to start the second node and wait for the working directory initialization so that all required folders associated with it's consistentId get generated.

After that if you copy `/db/<source_node_consistentId>/*` files to `/db/<new_node_consistentId>/*` and WAL files from `/wal/<sourceNode>/` if you haven't disable it, then the second node should start normally.

Comment: It was the first thought appeared, I'll try it and write back about the results. Thank you!

Comment: Added results to the top

Comment: Well, I have tested it with a simple scenario, just to verify that copying db files will work and no exception about duplicated consistentId would be thrown. Regarding the last one, I just remembered that IgniteConfiguration does have a _setConsistentId_ method that might help you as well.

Answer (score 1):

Thirty minutes seems excessive. There may be something else going on here, but if not you can tune rebalancing. There are a number of a [number of parameters](https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/modules/core/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/configuration/IgniteConfiguration.java#L1674) you can change. Maybe increase the batch size and the number of threads.

Comment: It was a synthetical test with a copy of real DB, so it's just copying. I'll try the Alexandr's suggestion firstly and if it fails will inspect this parameters